# TimerTask that gets system date and time stops running when System date is changed

Tags: java, swing

I've written a TimerTask to display current date and time in a JLabel. Following is the TimerTask code and that works well in normal scenario. When I change the system date and time when the GUI is running, the timer stops running. There was no exception when I changed system date and time and the Timer just stops running.
Can anyone tell me what is happening?

```
private void startTimer()
{
    // Start the clock
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimeTask(), 0, 1000);
}

class TimeTask extends TimerTask
{
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            clockLabel.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE , dd MMM , HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
            System.out.println(clockLabel.getText());
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use TimerTask with Swing as you can easily run into concurrency issues as TimerTask will be calling code off of the EDT. Instead use a Swing Timer; this is specifically what it is built for -- calling code periodically on the Swing event thread.

i.e.,

```
private void startTimer() {
  timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener());
  timer.start();
}

private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
  private final String PATTERN = "EEE , dd MMM , HH:mm:ss";
  private final DateFormat S_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(PATTERN);

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

     String dateString = S_DATE_FORMAT.format(date);
     clockLabel.setText(dateString);         
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- you have got issues with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), where output from `java.util.Timer` doesn't invoke [EventDispatchThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and represents Backgroung task for Swing GUI,
- since will be better to use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), because guarantee the output will be on EDT, but `Swing Timer` isn't accurate for long running taks in compare with `java.util.Timer`,
- for updating Swing GUI from any type of background tasks you have to wrap output to the Swing GUI into `invokeLater`

for example

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JLabel#setText();
    }
});
```